# Unknown symbol entries when grepping top output

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, gedit

I'm developing a bash script file that will log all CPU data, but when I log that data to log file I'm getting some irregular symbol entries in that log file.

```
echo "Hi" $(top -n 1 | grep 'Mem' | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d 't' -f1) >> tst1
```

This command will print total available memory. Now in the terminal I'm getting proper values, also in `cat` I'm getting proper values, but when I open this log file in gedit, at that time I'm getting some unknown symbol entries like:

> (B[m[39;49m(B[m 3918912k (B[m[39;49m

Now I don't know how this unknown guests get into my log file.

Comment: I'm sure you could also pipe some more `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `head`, `tail`, `cut`, `cat` to have an even more impressive command line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` uses [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to highlight memory values, which your terminal is able to interpret but your text editor isn't. For your need, you're probably better off reading `/proc/meminfo` directly, like this:

```
cat /proc/meminfo|grep MemTotal|awk '{print $2}' >> tst1
```

Comment: Useless use of cat spotted! Oh my, piping `cat`, `grep` and `awk` is just a bit too much for me.

Comment: I can use your command but i need many things to print so need to use top. Is there any way to convert that text to well format ?

Comment: +1 for `top -b`, if you need more data. Alternatively, you can `cat` the files which `top` uses to get the info: `/proc/meminfo`, `/proc/uptime`, `/proc/stat`, `/proc/loadavg`, etc...

Comment: echo "Hi" $(top -n 1 | grep 'Mem' | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d 't' -f1 | sed 's/ //g') >> tst1

I used this command now all blank space are removed still getting same output.